# lodash filter array of objects by an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects like below. I need to filter those array of objects using a filter object. Is there any method available in lodash does this. The filter object and the columns names of the filter objects are dynamic

**Array of objects**

```
[
  {
    "fname": "Stephanie",
    "lname": "Cotton",
    "status": "Inactive"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Jallis",
    "lname": "Buckley",
    "status": "Inactive"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Good",
    "lname": "Stuart",
    "status": "Inactive"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Jana",
    "lname": "Buckley",
    "status": "Inactive"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Welch",
    "lname": "Clay",
    "status": "Inactive"
  }
]
```

**Filter Object**

```
 {
   "fname":"ja",
    "lname":"Buckley"
 }
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    "fname": "Jallis",
    "lname": "Buckley",
    "status": "Inactive"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Jana",
    "lname": "Buckley",
    "status": "Inactive"
  },
]
```

Comment: codegeek - now the answer is dynamic for every filter

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(
  _.filter(tests, (value) => {
    for (let k of Object.keys(value)) {
      if (!_.startsWith(_.toLower(value[k]), _.toLower(filter[k]))) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  })
);
```

Comment: The filter columns names are dynamic so i cant hard code it

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you would achieve that using ES6 vanilla js:

```js
const array = [
      {
        "fname": "Stephanie",
        "lname": "Cotton",
        "status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "fname": "Jallis",
        "lname": "Buckley",
        "status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "fname": "Good",
        "lname": "Stuart",
        "status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "fname": "Jana",
        "lname": "Buckley",
        "status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "fname": "Welch",
        "lname": "Clay",
        "status": "Inactive"
      }
    ]
    
const filtered = array.filter(item=> item.fname.includes('Ja') && item.lname.includes('Buckley'));
console.log(filtered);
```